# How do i grep data out of a .txt document in linux?

Tags: linux, database, text, grep

I am trying to run a grep command on files on my server to find data from e.g. error logs and databases.

```
grep -r text file
```

I am running this command and it is not working responds with the error saying

```
Binary file "FILE"
```

Comment: The `-a` flag might be what you are looking for?

Comment: @KenY-N Hi I have solved this now but how do i grep data out of an .sql file?

Comment: why not query for it?

Comment: How do you query it Fallenreaper?

Comment: `select * from table where field like '%text%';`?

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for 
tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Typically an `.sql` file contains an SQL query , like above. The actual data retrieved by that query sits in a binary set of files, that the database software is designed to maintain and service (including query/extraction). You need to improve your Q, as it is unclear if you know which sort of search you need. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The file you are searching is not a normal text file, it's a binary file.

If u have a binary file, then most of it will be gibberish when u print it out but some might have ascii text.

To search for a string in a binary file you first need to print the content of the binary file and then pip the output to grep for searching.

`cat binaryfile  |  grep  searchstring`

You can directly give like this too :-

`grep searchstring  binaryfile`

If the given string is found it will reply with a string matched in binary file message. However unlike a normal text file and binary file doesn't have Line numbers as such for the ASCII text that you find in it. So grep will only say if it matched or not and doesn't give line number which makes sense.

Comment: Ok i see and I believe i fixed this error now with changing my database sources - How do i get data from a .sql file?